# "Error: Undeclared identifier" when trying to return a <Node> from a procedure

Tags: nim-lang

I post here a specific problem using a library (grim) in Nim, but the underlying concepts are still not super clear to me so I appreciate a solution coming with an explanation.

I would like to make a procedure returning a node. The example below is not really useful but makes the point: I want to `return node` but I apparently don't know what type it is.

```py
import grim
import sequtils

proc get_a_node_with_label(graph: Graph, label: string): Node =
  for node in graph.nodes:
    if node.label == label:
      return node

var g = newGraph("graph")
let n1 =  g.addNode("n1", %(Name: "first"))
let n2 =  g.addNode("n2", %(Name: "second"))

var aNode = get_a_node_with_label(g, "n2")
```

i get an  `Error: undeclared identifier: 'Node'`, but the type of "node" in the loop is "Node", if I `echo node.type`.

How should I deal with types on this occasion? What output should I declare in the procedure?

Thanks
Andrea

PS:  I apologize if the question is not well asked, and I'm happy to improve it with your guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably installed the `grim` library through `nimble install grim`. That gave you the `grim-0.2.0`, released early this year. The point is that `Node` was private in that release, so your code cannot access it.

You can opt to install the latest code, which at some point this year made `Node` and others public, with:

```
$ nimble uninstall grim
$ nimble install grim@#devel
```

Or you can make the object public in your computer, editing (probably) ~/.nimble/pkgs/grim-0.2.0/grim/graph.nim:

```
30 Node = ref object
```

to

```
30 Node* = ref object
```

---

The former includes the latest code, and includes 40ish commits. On the downside, your build will be hard to reproduce, because you cannot pin the `grim` version.

The later should allow you to compile locally, but you will run into problems if you intend to distribute your code (i.e. forcing you or your users to patch the grim source).

You could also open an issue at the github repo, asking the author to tag a new version.

---

You can get objects which class is `Node` (aka Node objects), but you cannot write "Node" in your code, and the only way of creating a Node object is through code that has access to the Node private class (i.e. in the same file). It is usually some kind of `newNode` or `getNode`.

So you could get a Node inside your code, and pass it around, but cannot write "Node". E.g.

```
import grim

var g = newGraph("graph")
let n1 = g.addNode("n1", %(Name: "first"))

# This works happily
let node = g.node(n1)  # This assigns a Node object to "node"
echo node              # This passes the Node object to a $ proc.

# This fails to compile, albeit being functionally the same code,
# because your program doesn't know what "Node" is.
let node1: Node = g.node(n1)
```

Comment: So if the class was to stay private there would be no way of passing it. But you can assign it to vars.